# Webform POST handler, add API/header creds?

Tags: 8, webforms

Using the Remote POST handler in Webform 5, is there a way to add basic auth / API key to the request leveraging tokens or referencing a const? I'd like to find a way not to hardcode actual values.

Comment: Sounds like you are going to want to define a custom webform handler. You can add settings to the settings form on the handler for your api keys. Try making a new one that extends the remote post handler to give you a head start. This way your keys end up in config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just adding an answer in addition to @Ryan Hartman's comment. Extend the `RemotePostWebformHandler` class and its `::buildConfigurationForm()` method:

```
/**
 * Custom Webform submission remote post handler.
 *
 * @WebformHandler(
 *   id = "custom_remote_post",
 *   ...
 * )  
 */
class CustomRemotePostWebformHandler extends RemotePostWebformHandler {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function buildConfigurationForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $form = parent::buildConfigurationForm($form, $form_state);

    $form['api_key'] = [
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => $this->t('API Key'),
      '#description' => $this->t('The API key for basic auth.'),
      '#default_value' => $this->configuration['api_key'] ?? NULL,
    ];

    return $form;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function submitConfigurationForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    parent::submitConfigurationForm($form, $form_state);

    $this->configuration['api_key'] = $form_state->getValue('api_key') ?: NULL;
  }

  ...
```

Alternatively implement the form element provided by the Key module so you can securely store sensitive secret keys.